# Наследование от модели без записи в БД EF6

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework

Заполняю datagridview вот так:

```
dgv_mainWindow.DataSource = _shift.Routes.OrderBy(r => r.SerialNumber).Select(r => new DatagridViewRoute {
    DetourKMs =r.DetourKMs,
    Distance = r.Distance,
    FromCityName = r.FromCityName,
    FromCode = r.FromCode,
    ToCode = r.ToCode,
    KGsTransported = r.KGsTransported,
    PalletsTransported = r.PalletsTransported,
    ArrivalTime = r.ArrivalTime,
    DepartureTime = r.DepartureTime,
    IdShift = r.Shift.Id,
    Id = r.Id
}).ToList();
```

Как выяснил при использовании анонимного типа ячейки грида становятся не доступными к редактированию. Для этого создал класс следующего вида:

```
public class DatagridViewRoute : Route
{
    public int IdShift { get; set; }
}
```

Так как практически все поля соответствуют кроме одного, я решил унаследоваться от модели, но при билде проекта ошибка миграции. Как сделать, что бы наследник абстрагировался от родителя в плане модельности и не участвовал в миграциях? Первое что приходит, это дубликат модель с изменением одного поля.

Comment: Правильно - не использовать наследование, а создать отдельный dto. Если надоест мапить ручками - перейти на автомаппер.

Comment: Ошибка миграции точно связана с этим изменением?

Comment: @tym32167 да, он мне говорит, что произошли изменения в структуре, а миграции нет.